# Selected Index of GridView has the value -1 on button click

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a `GridView` with an `ImageButton` on each row. I want to get value from a template field on clicking the button. I have used `SelectedIndex` in the `button_click`.

But the `SelectedIndex` is always -1.

The code I have tried is below.

```
   protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
   {
       int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
       Label t = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Label1");
       Session["course"] = t.Text;
       Response.Redirect("registration.aspx");
   }
```

Comment: The click of the button not necessarily selecting the row. Look at how the image is added and how you can force select the row when the image button is clicked.

Comment: I have used image button as a template field in gridview.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can go to row command where you can have click event of the image button.

[Grid View Row command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you won't get SelectedIndex in ButtonCLick event

so try like this

```
protected void imgbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        // Get the button that raised the event
        LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)sender;
        // Get the row that contains this button
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lnkbtn.NamingContainer;
        // Get rowindex
       int i = gvRow.RowIndex;
       Label t = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("Label1");
       Session["course"] = t.Text;
       Response.Redirect("registration.aspx");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

protected void grdview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if ((e.CommandName == "ImageButton")) {
            // Get RowIndex
            int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            // Get Row
            GridViewRow gvr = grdPhone.Rows(RowIndex);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) 
        {

    }
}
```

**ASPX:**

In GridView

you need to set CommandName and Argument like this

```
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtn_Click" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="ImageButton" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>Edit</asp:ImageButton >
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I don't think on click is will work in grid view and why it is required when you can write all your logic in onRowcommand .